# Unable to get Cycles renderer to output anything but grey

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

I've been trying to use the Cycles renderer in Blender 3.5 (problem happens in 3.1 as well) on a late-2019 Intel MacBook pro with an AD 5500M GPU. When I configure the material in the scene to use Cycles and switch the scene renderer to Cycles, rendering in the shaded viewport mode seems to work:

[image: Viewport render of simple object]

However, when I try to use `View > Viewport Render Image` all I get is a grey output. The object selection (orange outline) renders, so it seems it's trying to produce something:

[image: Image rendering of active viewport]

I've looked at my material setup, and looked at other people who've had rendering issues (object blocking camera, wrong camera focus settings, no compositor output, incorrect material setup) and I don't think any of these apply. My object has UVs, and I'm using the standard Principled BDSF shader. This is as simple of a scene as I can think to create - so I've attached my `.blend` file as well, in case anyone has an opportunity to look at it.

Here's my material setup in case there's something silly I'm doing here:

[image: shading setup in blender]

[image: macos system info dialog]

Attached .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render something in the viewport select the "Rendered" view underneath the tab bar. The way you rendered your image does not work with cycles. When rendering always press *Render > Render Image* or *Render Animation*.

Comment: I wasted so much time on this ... can't believe it was actually this trivial. And it is deeply and unfortunately confusing that this behavior is fragmented in this way. Thanks you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

[Blender Manual Note](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html)

> Viewport rendering only works for the Workbench and Eevee render
> engines. It’s not supported for Cycles.

p.s.: Definitely ready for proposal to enhance GUI.
Very confusing state now. I tried to [report it as papercuts](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-viewport-render-image/28790) ... so let see what will happens :)

Comment: Thanks you for your help! I accepted @CreativeDrone_'s answer because they are new to this site, but also because they provided a more complete answer on how to get the result. But I very much appreciate your answer as well.